# JS - scrollTop doesn't work in mobile and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have fixed height div and need to **add scroll up event**, my current code works in chrome but doesn't work in firefox and mobile devices.

alert shows when

- reaching TOP of div(from PC chrome)
- reaching bottom of div(from mobile and firefox)

**Note:** I need a solution in vanilla js, not jquery.

**CODE:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            margin: 5% auto;
            width: 40%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }

        .chat {
            border: 1px ridge #34495e;
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
                -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
                    flex-direction: column-reverse;
            max-height: 500px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="chat" id="my_id">
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>
            <p>TEST1</p>            
            <p>TEST2</p>                        
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var el = document.querySelector("#my_id")

      el.addEventListener("scroll",function (){
        if (el.scrollTop == 0) {
           alert("Load old messages")
        }
      })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please could you add a working, minimal example snippet so we can try it on different browsers? In particular I think we need to see the element you are scrolling and any other CSS relating to it like overflow.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nikushamikusha/pen/NWrOGMa

Comment: Chrome, Edge and Firefox (on Windows 10) all gave me the same result - I saw the alert as I scrolled to the bottom in each case.

Comment: Also saw the alert as I scrolled to the bottom on iPadIOS 14 Safari

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `console.log(el.scrollTop)` as the first line in the event listening function you'll see that the amount scrolled is 0 when you are scrolled to the bottom of the element and as you scroll up the amount scrolled gets more and more negative.

Notice that .chat has several settings related to flex/column:

```
 display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
            -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse;
                flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

I cannot tell from what is in the question which of these is essential for your particular use case, but if you comment them all out you'll notice that the amount scrolled goes to the expected 0 when you are at the top of the element and gets steadily larger as you scroll down.

My suggestion would be to go through each of those settings in .chat and decide what is needed for your case and what is not. It is likely to be those settings that are reversing the order that are making the difference. You may know why this was done for this particular application.

Comment: I think you are right. I wanted to automatically scroll down on the chat container and I used the CSS trick, but I should do auto-scroll down using javascript